# How do I properly display with buttons?

Tags: html

I'm a beginner with HTML. I have some code down with buttons and they are a pain but I have no idea how to fix this. I have buttons that are displaying information, every time I click on them, the info is displayed ABOVE the info that I want to be hidden whenever a new button is clicked to display new info. please help! I want to learn how to actually fix this so I don't run into this in the future.

```html
<div style="width: 800px; height: 60px; margin: 0 auto; border-color: #FFFFFF; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; background-color: #000000; padding:15px;">
<font face="impact" color="white"><center><font size="10">☼CLYDE☼</font face></div>

<br><div style="width: 800px; height: 300px; margin:0 auto; border-color: #ffffff; border-width: 5px; border-style: double; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); padding: 10px;"><table style="margin: 1px"><tbody><tr><td><div style="width: 32px; height: 266px; border-color: white; border-style: inset; padding: 3px;"><button title="basics" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}" type="button"><font size="5">♡</font size></button>

<br><br><button title="love life" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler1') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler1') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler1') .style.display='none'}" type="button"><font size="5">♡</font size></button>

<br><br><button title="more basics" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display='none'}" type="button"><font size="5">♡</font size></button>

<br><br><button title="interactions" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler3') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler3') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler3') .style.display='none'}" type="button"><font size="5">♡</font size></button>

<br><br><button title="gallery" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler4') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler4') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler4') .style.display='none'}" type="button"><font size="5">♡</font size></button></div></td><td><div style="width: 500px; height: 244px; margin: 1.5%; border-color: #FFFFFF; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; background-color: #000000; padding: 15px;"><div id="spoiler" style="display:none;"><font color="white"><font face="monospace"><p align="left"><b>name___</b> clyde, but please call him princess
<b>age___</b> twenty-seven months
<b>gender___</b> feminine male ( xy )
<b>pronouns___</b> he/him/his
<b>sexuality___</b> panromantic homoflexible ( preference for masculinity )

<b>rank___</b> warrior
<b>residence___</b> glacierclan ( unofficially 'gaycierclan' )
<b>student___</b> possibly doekit
<b>teacher___</b> cherrystalk, a fae in the past</font></font></div><div id="spoiler1" style="display:none;"><font color="white"><font face="monospace"><b>bronze rose___</b> snowbird, she's the only one to comfort him
<b>silver rose___</b> cosmo and mikasa, they make him shiver in delight
<b>golden rose___</b> hopefully soon
<b>wilted rose___</b> no mention

<b>family___</b> sequoiamask ( father ), clementine ( mother ), coralflame ( sister ), powderedtoe ( sister ), leliana ( sister )
<b>adopted family___</b> none
<b>offspring___</b> hopefully soon</font></font></div><div id="spoiler2" style="display:none;"><font color="white"><font face="monospace"><b>fragrance___</b> peaches and cream
<b>jewels___</b> a lovely aquamarine
<b>coat___</b> a brown peachy undertone with cinnamon freckles, coca dapples, and milky white dapples
<b>vocals___</b> troye sivan ( a soft masculine tone )

<b>personality___</b> timid, shy, anxious, nervous
<b>disorders___</b> over the months, clyde has unfortunately developed social anxiety, please be patient with him
<b>fears___</b> arsonphobia ( fire ), ruining his pelt or acquiring scars
<b>quirks___</b> nips at paws when under stress or anxiety, sleeps a lot, very easy to get crushes or attraction</font></font></div><div id="spoiler3" style="display:none;"><font color="white"><font face="monospace"><b>koikit ( koi )___</b> "she's really kind, and i liker her name!"
<b>salmonflame ( tanzi )___</b> "she's a gentle she-cat, i enjoy her company."
<b>doekit ( tanzi )___</b> "a cute one that is!"
<b>snowbird ( snow-bird )___</b> "i trust her with everything. she's always there for me, and i'm so glad to call her a friend. she has a special place in my heart... she knows how to make me smile."
<b>cosmo ( vanic )___</b> "i-i feel weird around him.. he makes me burn in a lovely way and he knows his way with words. he's charming too.. but i don't think he feels the same? i've seen him with another.."
<b>ricepaw ( freak-show )___</b> "we met awkwardly."
<b>mikasa ( nightlystars )___</b>  "s-she's a very pretty she-cat, even with that scar of hers. she's the first feline to claim that they trust me... i'm not sure how i feel about her, but there's something."</font></font></div><div id="spoiler4" style="display:none;"><font color="white"><font face="monospace">wip.</font></font></div><font color="white"><font face="monospace"><font size="7">⸰ ⸰ ⸰ ⸰ ⸰</font size>
<br>now turn away,
'cause i'm awful just to see, 'cause all my hair's abandoned all my body
all my agony . . . know that i will never marry, baby i'm just soggy from the chemo, but i'm counting down the days to go
it just ain't living, and i just hope you know, that if you say, goodbye today
i'd ask you to be true, 'cause the hardest part of this is leaving you . . .</font></font></div></td></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: First of all you have to understand how to separate the code's/application's concerns.
i.e. Seperate the HTML, CSS and JavaScript part in different files.
Yes this will be difficult if your a beginner. But try to practice in following such conduct so that u can maintain & search the bugs in the code.

Comment: this is the code that i'm using inside an html editor for another website. it's a pop-up window that a user can customize for themselves with the html code that they create. css and javascript aren't used, so i don't have to organize any different files for it.

Comment: I doubt, if you have written this code on your own.  `"width: 800px; height: 60px; margin: 0 auto; border-color: #FFFFFF; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; background-color: #000000; padding:15px;` this is inline css and 
`if(document.getElementById('spoiler1') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler1') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler1') .style.display='none'}` this is JavaScript

Comment: i made the div code myself and my other friend helped me with the organization of using buttons and sent me the code for it & explained what some aspects mean.

Answer (score 0):

Review your extra space in `('spoiler') .style.`

```
                                   ^
```

You have a lot of extra spaces